# can we use 'assign' like this?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, meaning-in-context, syntactic-analysis, sentence

In my article, there's a part that I want to say that we should keep some of our old buildings because of its historical value and implement our city development plans in another area. so is this sentence correct or not:

- we should assign a special and limited area for these old buildings.

Comment: Assign *to*, reserve *for*. Pick one. Though I'm not sure how either one is possible at all. Presumably if the buildings are *old*, they are *already there*. They don't need to be assigned an area. They already occupy it.

Comment: Hello, imannoodi. Do online dictionaries give any example sentences of the same form? If you do some research, and say 'Lexico, Collins and AHD do not give sentences showing 'assign something for something else', with links, this becomes a really valid question.

Comment: @Reg 'Have you assigned a day for the interviews yet?' ([CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/assign?)). Assign X for Y = set aside X for Y. Though here, one is inescapably left with the prospect of moving the old buildings (it has been done).

Comment: 'Ring-fence' is probably too metaphor-orientated to use here! Instead of 'assign', 'set apart' is not overly formal; I don't know whether  'place a preservation order on' can be applied to a district, or whether it's a common term outside the UK.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "assign" I would use "designate", given by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/designate) as

> **designate**
>   VERB
>
> **1.1** Officially give a specified status or name to.
>   Example: *The Wye Valley is designated an area of outstanding natural beauty.*

The phrase for protected land used in UK is "a conservation area", given by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/conservation_area) as

> **conservation area**
>   NOUN
>   *British*
>
> An area of notable environmental or historical interest or importance which is protected by law against undesirable changes.
>   Example: *If a property is within a conservation area then any development needs to be carefully assessed by planning authorities.*

So I would write

> We should designate a conservation area to protect these old buildings.

Comment: This advice is spot on, so I won't downvote for it not being an 'answer' to the actual  question.